# "Release>nil>init" An acceptable way to update an NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, nsmutabledictionary

Is the method below an acceptable (i.e. best-practices, non-hacky) way of updating an NSMutableDictionary?

Basically I want the method to check if the dictionary has been initialized/populated yet. If it has NOT then I want it to go ahead and populate it with a certain set of iVars I have, with the matching set of keys.

If it HAS already been initialized/populated though, I want a refresh, and I wanted to avoid having to write out `setObject:forKey:` for every single element in the dict.

So...

1. Is "Release">"Set nil">"Re-init" an acceptable approach to refreshing this dictionary?
2. If so, is that the *only* way to do it for a dictionary of large values unless I want to repeat line after line of `setObject:forKey:`

Thanks! Code follows:

```
- (void) populateFetchDataDict {

    if (!self.fetchDataDict) {
        self.fetchDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, @"key1", object2, @"key2", object3, @"key3", object4, @"key4", nil];
    } else {
        [fetchDataDict release];
        fetchDataDict = nil;
        self.fetchDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, @"key1", object2, @"key2", object3, @"key3", object4, @"key4", nil];
    }

}
```

Minor notes:

- `fetchDataDict` is an iVar, as are all of the objects, so assume the `object1`, `object2`, etc. would actually be `self.object1`, `self.object2`...
- Also, I accessed the `fetchDataDict` iVar directly for `release` and `nil`, as I thought that's what we're supposed to do, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

**This question is learning-focused, so long explanations are welcome!**

Comment: what about setDictionary? - For the ivar itself, that's recommended in your dealloc method, otherwise you can just set a new value with dot notation, and the old one will be released and the new one retained. Also you're over retaining your dictionary with alloc init, and no autorelease, then storing in a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using property accessors, and I am assuming you have the properties marked as `retain`, you can simply set the new value - the old will be released automatically.  In fact the only reason your code doesn't crash right now is because you are over-retaining the new dictionaries by not autoreleasing them, which you should do.

In fact your code can simply look like:

```
- (void) populateFetchDataDict {
        self.fetchDataDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, @"key1", object2, @"key2", object3, @"key3", object4, @"key4", nil];
}
```

If you only wanted to set those specific values in an existing dictionary, then you could add back in the if statement and merge in those default values with the existing dictionary:

```
- (void) populateFetchDataDict {

        NSDictionary *defaultDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictonaryWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, @"key1", object2, @"key2", object3, @"key3", object4, @"key4", nil];
    if (!self.fetchDataDict) {
        self.fetchDataDict = defaultDict;
    } else {
        [self.fetchDataDict addEntriesFromDictionary:defaultDict];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kendall. So I don't ever need to alloc/init this dict if using property accessors? I assumed I would need to the first time I called it, hence my (apparently buggy) code. Also, if using `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` will it simply overwrite old values if the dict has already been populated?

Comment: The dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: call is doing an alloc/init/autorelease for you... the code I have that does "add" will only replace keys that are in the dictionary you pass it, all other keys you already have set will be kept as is